# SetEnvIfNoCase not setting variable value properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, setenvif

I need to access service running at domain (`example.com`) from two different apps running at different ports of localhost but getting CORS error.

PageURL accessed in browser  is:

```
http://localhost:8081/weather
```

which internally sending AJAX request to

```
example.com/getResponse
```

I have CORS header configured in Apache of (`example.com`) as follows:

```
SetEnvIfNocase Origin "http://localhost:8085" CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN1=$0
Header append Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN1}e env=CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN1
SetEnvIfNocase Origin "http://localhost:8081" CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN2=$0
Header append Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN2}e env=CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN2
```

Now Request Headers are:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Host: example.com
Origin: http://localhost:8081
Referer: http://localhost:8081/weather
User-Agent: Mozilla
```

Getting Response Header as:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $0
```

Obviously, the error comes back as:

> CORS Blocked: Reason: CORS Header does not match '$0'

The presence of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` Header in response means `SetEnvIfNoCase` executes and matches the `Origin` Request-Header value.

My question is why `$0` is not getting replaced by the whole string getting matched?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is why `$0` is not getting replaced by the whole string getting matched.?

This is bug-like<sup>1</sup> (IMO) behaviour of the `SetEnvIf[NoCase]` directive. In situations when the 2nd argument doesn't "look like" a regex, the entire match is not captured, no backreferences are generated, and instead `$0` is seen as a literal string.

It is preferable to be explicit and include a capturing group (parenthesised subpattern) and use the `$1` backreference instead.

For example:

```
SetEnvIfNocase Origin "^(http://localhost:8085)" CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN1=$1
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> Or maybe an optimisation?! It behaves like a simple substring().</sub>

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> SetEnvIfNocase Origin "http://localhost:8085" CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN1=$0
> Header append Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN1}e env=CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN1
> SetEnvIfNocase Origin "http://localhost:8081" CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN2=$0
> Header append Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN2}e env=CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN2
> ```

It's not clear why you would need two expressions (and two variables) here, since these are *mutually exclusive* events. For example, the same result would be achieved with the following:

```
SetEnvIf Origin "^(http://localhost:808[51])" CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=$1
Header append Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN}e env=CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN
```

(A case-insensitive match would also seem to be redundant here.)